# Counting instances of modules in SystemVerilog

Tags: module, static, instance, system-verilog, modelsim

I am attempting to design a simple CPU and I ma using SystemVerilog to design and ModelSim to simulate the design. I am trying to set up some code to count the number of instances of a specific module. I am currently using static variables to try to achieve this however it is not working. My code is as follows.

```
module testbench;

logic a0, b0, y0;
logic a1, b1, y1;
logic a2, b2, y2;

AND and0(.a(a0), .b(b0), .y(y0));
AND and1(.a(a1), .b(b1), .y(y1));
AND or0(.a(a2), .b(b2), .y(y2));

initial
begin
    $display("AND Gates : ", and0.instance_count);
    $display("OR Gates : ", or0.instance_count);
end

endmodule



module AND(input logic a, b, output logic y);

static int instance_count = 0;

initial
    instance_count++;

and(y, a, b);

endmodule



module OR(input logic a, b, output logic y);

static int instance_count = 0;

initial
    instance_count++;

or(y, a, b);

endmodule
```

The output this gives is 1 instance for both the AND gates and OR gates, which is incorrect. How could I change my code to fix this issue? In addition to this, a solution to this problem which can be determined through modelsim and not require me to add any code to my model would be an ideal solution, if that is possible.

Comment: I am planning to create the circuit on breadboards as a summer project and my main aim is to design a functional CPU with a very small number of logic gates such that this is possible. It's not that I am trying to instantiate this many gates, is that I want to count the number of gates I have used after I have designed the CPU.

Comment: Surely there must be a better way to do this, I don't want to be counting 10s-100s of messages every time I want to determine the gate count.

Comment: Grep -c could be a lightweight solution.

Comment: you can create a VPI function (in C) to count them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All declarations at the module level are already `static`, and each module instance has a separate allocation of variable instances.

You could create a global package with an associative array.

```
package inst;
int count[string] = '{default:0};
endpackage

module AND(input logic a, b, output logic y);

initial inst::count["AND"]++;

and(y, a, b);

endmodule
```

SystemVerilog has no built-in introspection, but there [are ways](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/DQDG) of building it in to your flow if you really want to dive into the VPI details.

But many tools including ModelSim have Tcl commands like

```
find instances -r /testbench/* -file instances.txt
```

that would be easy to write a counting script of individual instances.